# Splitting a view controller horizontally

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, viewcontroller

i want to split a view controller in 2 parts horizontally maintaining an aspect ratio.
Is there any way to this?

Comment: The question is too unclear to answer, what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: for iPhone or iPad ?

Comment: yes, you can get height and width of screen. But what is the question?

Comment: i want set two images on the screen but they always get disaffirmed even with auto layout on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

you can take reference from [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) which can be replaced with SplitViewController. I hope you will get an idea about it.